# QR-Code scanner connected to raspberry pi 4 does not execute command

Tags: keyboard

I have set up a raspberry pi and connected a QR-Code scanner via a dongle to it so the QR-Code scanner acts as keyboard. The scanner is set up to send `my-command`  as prefix and then whatever is coded in the QR-code. The function `my-command` is defined in the `.bashrc` file of the pi user and logs something to the system log.

If I log in via ssh and type `my-command`, the log message appears in journalctl. However, it seems that the command is not executed with the QR-Code scanner. I can, however, see that the scanner sends the keystrokes by following `evtest`.

I have this problem on a raspberry pi 4. I've previously set it up on a raspberry pi 2 were it worked.

Background: I want to set up the QR-code scanner such that the kids can use it to play music. For this, `my-command` is supposed to send a MQTT message which will be received by the server that does the rest.

Comment: what is your question that actually relates to the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: use a text editor to test the scanner